# how to get the count of data based on status id in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

```
 i have following table
 
    id  statusid
    100   1
    100   2
    100   3
    101   1
    101   3 

  i am getting the result like following  

id    data1 data2 data3
100    1     1     1
101    1     0     1
```

but i want the result like following

```
id    data1 data2+data3
100    1     2
101    1     1
```

i am using the following query:

```
select id, SUM(CASE WHEN statusid=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS data1,
SUM(CASE WHEN statusid=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS data2,
SUM(CASE WHEN statusid=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS data3
from employee
group by id
```

any help.

thank you.
Sudha.

Comment: Can the status id be anything other than 1, 2 or 3? In particular, can it be NULL? In that case, what do you **really** need to count? For example: if you need to count rows with status id 2 or 3, GMB has already given you the answer. If you must count all rows with status id **other than 1**, you can write a similar conditional count - but make sure NULL is handled correctly, if NULL is possible in the STATUSID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count statuses 2 and 3 together like so:

```
select id, 
    sum(case when statusid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as data1,
    sum(case when statusid in (2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) as data2_3
from employee
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`PIVOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDCEJJE) clause to get the required result.

Use `DECODE` to map the status so that the `2` and `3` produce the same value

```
with tab2 as (select 
id, decode(status_id,3,2,status_id) status_id2
from tab)
select * from tab2
PIVOT (count(*) "CNT"  for status_id2 in 
(1 as "DATA_1",
 2 as "DATA_2_3")
)

        ID DATA_1_CNT DATA_2_3_CNT
---------- ---------- ------------
       100          1            2
       101          1            1
```

Comment: Actually based on the syntax of the `expr`om the [pivot_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__CHDCEJJE) I'd assume that  `(2,3)  as "DATA_2_3"` should be possible and it would be a *more ellegant solution*, but this returns `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` even in 19c.